# Is there any way to create a link between file inside container docker and host?

Tags: docker

I wanna create a link between only one file inside container docker and docket host. I only know a way to create between folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `-v` option lets you mount a host file into the Docker container.

From the [Docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-file-as-a-data-volume):

> The -v flag can also be used to mount a single file - instead of just
>   directories - from the host machine.
>
> `$ docker run -it -v ~/my.log:/some.log ubuntu /bin/bash`